# SQL: check constraint and on delete clauses

Tags: sql

I created two tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE Horse (
ID              SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
RegisteredName  VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (ID))

CREATE TABLE Student (
ID             SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName      VARCHAR(20),
LastName        VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

For the third table, I want it to meet the following requirements:

1.HorseID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, not NULL, partial primary key, foreign key references Horse(ID)

2.StudentID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, foreign key references Student(ID)

3.LessonDateTime - date/time, not NULL, partial primary key

4.If a row is deleted from Horse, the rows with the same horse ID should be deleted from LessonSchedule automatically.

5.If a row is deleted from Student, the same student IDs should be set to NULL in LessonSchedule automatically.

Here is the query:
(For some reason, I was not able to put the codes below in a code block.)

```
CREATE TABLE LessonSchedule (
HorseID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL CHECK(HorseID BETWEEN 0 AND 65000),
StudentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED CHECK(StudentID BETWEEN 0 AND 65000),
LessonDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (HorseID, LessonDateTime),
FOREIGN KEY(HorseID) REFERENCES Horse(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Student(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL)
```

> I got an erroe message: Column 'StudentID' cannot be used in a check
> constraint 'lessonschedule_chk_2': needed in a foreign key constraint
> 'lessonschedule_ibfk_2' referential action.

Here are my questions:

1. Based on the error  message, can anyone tells me what my query went wrong?
2. Did I do it right putting the two ON DELETE clauses at the end of the two foreign key statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same class and here is the correct code.

CREATE TABLE Horse (
ID              SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
RegisteredName  VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Student (
ID             SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName      VARCHAR(20),
LastName        VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE LessonSchedule (
HorseID        SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
StudentID      SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
LessonDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (HorseID, LessonDateTime),
FOREIGN KEY (HORSEID) REFERENCES Horse(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
);